# Cannot cast OneTimeEnumerable to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

So, I'm currently working on a small client application with an MSSQL database backend.

I've been making use of Linq to SQL, and therein `CompiledQuery`. However, when retrieving a list of objects from the database, I'm getting an `InvalidCastException` with the message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'OneTimeEnumerable`1[DiallerBlacklistManager.Data.Entities.BlacklistDataContext.BlacklistEntry]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

This is the first time I've ever encountered this error, and I'm a little at a loss as to what it is referring to.

My compiled query Func looks like so:

```
    public static Func<BlacklistDataContext, DateTime, DateTime, List<BlacklistEntry>>
        GetBlacklistEntriesByBlacklistDateRangeFunc =
            CompiledQuery.Compile<BlacklistDataContext, DateTime, DateTime, List<BlacklistEntry>>(
                (db, startTime, endTime) =>
                    (from BlacklistEntry e in db.BlacklistEntries
                        where e.BlacklistDate >= startTime && e.BlacklistDate <= endTime
                        select e).ToList());
```

And the method that calls it:

```
    public List<BlacklistEntryDisplayItem> DoSearch(string searchText, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime,
        bool includeDeleted)
    {
        List<BlacklistEntryDisplayItem> output = new List<BlacklistEntryDisplayItem>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            output.AddRange(GetBlacklistEntriesBySearchAndDateRange(searchText, startTime, endTime).Select(be => (BlacklistEntryDisplayItem) be));
            if (includeDeleted)
            {
                output.AddRange(
                    GetDeletedBlacklistEntriesBySearchAndDateRange(searchText, startTime, endTime)
                        .Select(be => (BlacklistEntryDisplayItem) be));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output.AddRange(GetBlacklistEntriesByDateRange(startTime, endTime).Select(be => (BlacklistEntryDisplayItem)be));
            if (includeDeleted)
            {
                output.AddRange(
                    GetDeletedBlacklistEntriesByBlacklistDateRange(startTime, endTime)
                        .Select(be => (BlacklistEntryDisplayItem) be));
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Note that `BlacklistEntryDisplayItem` is a class used for displaying both `BlacklistEntry` and `DeletedBlacklistEntry`in a single type, for tidiness. (It was specified that deleted entries must be stored in a separate table)

In case it is seen as relevant, the `BlacklistEntryDisplayItem` class is:

```
public class BlacklistEntryDisplayItem
{
    public BlacklistEntryDisplayItem(int id, string phoneNumber, DateTime blacklistDate, string comments, int userId, bool deleted)
    {
        Id = id;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        BlacklistDate = blacklistDate;
        Comments = comments;
        UserId = userId;
        Deleted = deleted;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; private set; }

    public DateTime BlacklistDate { get; private set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; private set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator BlacklistEntryDisplayItem(BlacklistEntry entry)
    {
        return new BlacklistEntryDisplayItem(
            entry.Id, 
            entry.PhoneNumber, 
            entry.BlacklistDate, 
            entry.Comments, 
            entry.UserId, 
            false);
    }

    public static implicit operator BlacklistEntryDisplayItem(DeletedBlacklistEntry entry)
    {
        return new BlacklistEntryDisplayItem(
            entry.Id,
            entry.PhoneNumber,
            entry.BlacklistDate,
            entry.Comments,
            entry.UserId,
            true);
    }
}
```

Is anybody able to advise what `OneTimeEnumerable` is, and why the result set is not of the type defined in the Func type parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me before. The cause of the issue is the `ToList` in your compiled query block. Compiled queries apparently only return `OneTimeEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`. Remove the `ToList` and have your compiled query return `IEnumerable<BlacklistEntry>` instead and then call `ToList` after calling the compiled query.

```
public static Func<BlacklistDataContext, DateTime, DateTime, IEnumerable<BlacklistEntry>>
    GetBlacklistEntriesByBlacklistDateRangeFunc =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<BlacklistDataContext, DateTime, DateTime, List<BlacklistEntry>>(
            (db, startTime, endTime) =>
                from BlacklistEntry e in db.BlacklistEntries
                where e.BlacklistDate >= startTime && e.BlacklistDate <= endTime
                select e);
```

and then use it like this:

```
GetBlacklistEntriesByBlacklistDateRangeFunc(dataContext, startTime, endTime).ToList()
```